# Test Net not syncing

Tags: ether, synchronization, testnets

I sent my presale wallet to the main account of my Mist Eth Wallet using MyEtherWallet.com. It said it sent and my presale wallet is empty but it has not showed up on my Mist wallet yet. Also it says TEST-NET on the top left. Do I have to get out of the TEST-NET before i can see my sent ETH? If so how to I do that? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

**Q**: Do I have to get out of the TEST-NET before i can see my sent ETH?

Yes

**Q**: If so how to I do that?
Select the menu Develop -> Network -> Main Network.

You will have to switch from Test Net to the main network, then wait for the blockchain to sync on your computer. This could take some time if you have partially synced with the main Ethereum network before. Search "mist fast" or "ethereum wallet fast" on this site if you find that your syncing is progressing slowly.

If you want to check your balances while your computer is syncing the blockchain, use the public blockchain explorers like http://etherscan.io/ and you should see your transferred balance in your new account address.

Answer (score 2):

Test net is just that: for sending 'fake' ether and experimenting with the network.  You want to be on the main net for real ether.  You can switch as per BokkyPooBah's answer.  Pay close attention to what you do on mainnet, you can't get your ether back once it has been sent.